# Stack space of a child thread

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a thread A, from main function, which in turn spawns another child thread B. I want to explicitly assign the stack size to threads A and B using `pthread_attr_setstacksize()`.

As per the requirement, the stack size of parent thread A is smaller than the child thread B.

I am confused that if the stack of a child thread is allocated from stack space of  parent thread or the stack space of parent and child thread are completely different.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The stacks for two threads/process are completely different. None of them is allocated from another.

Comment: @Michael: Well, since the OP is apparently on Linux, they *could* use `clone()` and set up the child stack at an address inside of the parent's stack.

Comment: @EOF The `man clone()` says:`Since the child and calling process may share memory, it is not possible for the child process to execute in the same stack as the calling process. The calling process must therefore set up memory space for the child stack and pass a pointer to this space to clone().` You can always break the rules intentionally. But it is not what the `clone()` developers expect you to do.

Comment: @Michael: I wasn't advocating doing this. But you *could*. It *might* even work, if you chose a part of the stack that the parent isn't using.

Comment: @EOF Yes, I could. But we are talking about a newcomer. Let's keep things simple at the beginning

Comment: Thank you @Michael for answering my question. It is clear to me know.

Comment: Thank you @EOF for answering my question, your explanation is clear to me.

Comment: @Michael That is not entirely correct. The stacks of two threads are different, however, stacks of parent/child processes are the same until child or parent changes something on stack, in that case that part of the stack gets copied.

Comment: @Aleksandar Makragić As I've said before, let's keep things simple. Copy-on-write of the stack is a little bit advanced for such a basic question.

Comment: There is no parent/child concept for threads as there is for processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to explicitly assign the stack size to threads A and B using pthread_attr_setstacksize().

So, you do so:

```
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_t       A, B;
    void           *A_retval, *B_retval;
    int             result;

    result = pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize thread attributes: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, A_STACK_SIZE);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set stack size %zu for thread A: %s.\n", (size_t)A_STACK_SIZE, strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = pthread_create(&A, &attrs, A_FUNCTION, NULL);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread A: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, B_STACK_SIZE);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set stack size %zu for thread B: %s.\n", (size_t)A_STACK_SIZE, strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = pthread_create(&B, &attrs, B_FUNCTION, NULL);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create thread A: %s.\n", strerror(result));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    /* TODO: Perhaps this thread also does something? */

    /* Wait for A and B to exit. */

    result = pthread_join(A, &A_retval);
    if (result)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Thread A: %s.\n", strerror(result));

    result = pthread_join(B, &B_retval);
    if (result)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Thread B: %s.\n", strerror(result));
```

> As per the requirement, the stack size of parent thread A is smaller than the child thread B.

Just make sure the sizes are a multiple of page size ([`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)), and at least `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`.

There are no parent or child threads. They are all "siblings", belonging to the same process. There is a "main thread", which is the sole thread when the process is started, but it is not special in any way. It gets its name from `main()`, as it is the thread that starts running that function. It does not matter which thread created some other thread, at all.

If there is a parent-child relationship mentioned between threads in some code, then it is used to reflect the *logic of the code*, not the threads' actual relationship. *"Parent"* and *"child"* are just easy shorthand for *"the thread that created the newly created thread"* and *"the newly created thread"*.

Processes do have real parent-child relationships -- for example, only a parent can reap its child --, but all threads are siblings within a process in Linux: any thread can join/reap any other thread in the same process.

> I am confused that if the stack of a child thread is allocated from stack space of parent thread or the stack space of parent and child thread are completely different.

No, each thread has their own separate stack. This new stack is almost always allocated and prepared by the `pthread_create()` call automatically, using the desired stack size if attributes are specified, or default stack size (which is huge, several megabytes) if no attributes are specified.

(There is a `pthread_attr_setstack()` call for setting up an explicit stack for the next thread created using that set of attributes. Some really oddball applications may need specific stack arrangements. The stack area is not just some random chunk of memory; it does need to be properly aligned, sufficiently large, and so on. It is possible to allocate it yourself using `mmap()` for example, but it is definitely not something you should ever need, or want, to do.)

---

It may be interesting or informative to see the memory regions used by the program itself, or by some specific process.

In Linux, your program can open and read `/proc/self/maps` pseudofile (it is not a real file on disk, but a file-like entity that the kernel generates on the fly when you open and read it), or you can read any `/proc/PID/maps` corresponding to process ID `PID`.

The first two hexadecimal numbers on each line describe the address range, and stacks are marked `[stack]`.

See [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for further information on the files in the `/proc` pseudofilesystem.